# Would like to add a 14-30 outlet in my garage

Tags: electrical-panel

I am looking to add a 14-30 outlet in my garage. My panel is right where I would add the outlet too.
Just trying to understand my own electrical panel a bit before I go further. Attached are the pictures of my panel and the GE spec sheet.

My understanding is:

- Panel supports 200amp
- I have 30,30,50 circuit breakers in my top section that is always hot.
- My lower section can support max of 100amp breaker but is using a 60amp breaker right now

So I am thinking I could:

- Change the 60 amp breaker to 80 or 90 amp breaker
- Add a 240/30amp breaker to the lower section
- Connect that to a 14-30 outlet

Things I am not sure of:

- Can you add double pole breakers to the lower section?
- I see a 27 poles maximum, is that in total or just for the lower section?
- From the spec sheet, I see 8 poles on each side but on my actual panel, I think I only see 6 being used on each side? So there should still be 2 poles available on each side?

And lastly, I will definitely be getting a professional to do the work but wanted to understand what options I have before hand too. Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'll defer to the electricians here, but i think you have a "rule of six" panel.   The lower fuses listed furnace,  washer, 28 thru 32 are probably double stab breakers.(one breaker with two independent circuits on them.)

Comment: Now might be a great time to replace panel with a newer 200 amp 40 breaker/80 circuit panel. Give you lots of expansion room.

Comment: How many square feet is your house, what's the nameplate minimum circuit ampacity (MCA) on your air conditioner, and what's the amp rating of the breaker in spot 11/13 (top left breaker in the bottom bank with the receptacle symbol next to it) as I can't read it from the photo due to glare?  Also, what are you planning to plug into this new receptacle?

Answer (score 3):

What you have here is called a "split bus panel".   There is no main breaker and as Limo Driver said, it follows the "rule of six" which means it must be possible to cut all power with 6 movements of your hand, you can cut all power with 4, so you're in good shape that way. But the panel is FULL! The 2 "unused" spaces are probably not available because there are connection lugs behind them. A picture of the innards of the panel would be helpful to get better advice.

Also, it's impossible to feed generator power to a panel like this safely unless you get one of those rinky dinky generac transfer switches with individual breakers. The master electricians here prefer a manual interlock on the main breaker so you can power the entire house from the generator, but that's not possible here.

Another consideration would be a sub-panel. You could upgrade the sub-main breaker from 60 to 100 amps, move some circuits to the sub-panel to make room for your 14-30 outlet.  But that's kind of a kludge.  Less expensive than a full panel replacement, but still a kludge.  If it were my house, I'd do a full panel replacement with a 40 space panel.  I also noticed you're in Washington State (me too), and we have our share of wind storms and power outages. So if you do this, you might want to consider  a breaker for the generator and a generator interlock between the generator breaker and the main breaker.

Comment: The rule of 6 was a standard panel but is no longer allowed by code. I agree with George a sub may be the least expensive / best route forward since you have a 200 amp panel. When I updated my home  I removed the rule of 6 and installed a main breaker panel 200a and a mechanical interlock for a generator it cost a bit more than a sub but my panel is in the dining room and I did not want 2.  There is no requirement to update the split buss panel they are not allowed on new installs per the NEC and you are on the latest 2020 version.

Comment: Normally I would expect those unused knock out plates to not be available too, but the poles in the "typical wiring diagram" sent me searching and I found this https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/installing-a-sub-panel-to-a-ge-split-bus-panel .

Comment: @NoSparksPlease  Could be, that's why I asked for a pic of the innards, even if available, the OP would have to move a breaker to make room for a double pole breaker in the sub-main portion of the panel .

Comment: @EdBeal   Since you have the skills to do that, it makes total sense, but it gets expensive for others. In my previous home, I installed a sub-panel with a built in MTS and moved most circuits to it. It was a simple portable generator with a proper power inlet, (5,000 watts if I remember correctly), It was fed by a split bus panel, but it was OK since the MTS was downstream of the main panel.  When I added a heat pump (with backup electrical resistant heating),   an addition to the house and a shop, I finally upgraded the split bus panel to a 40 space panel with a main breaker.

Comment: George I did state your sub was the least expensive/ best route and up voted but suggested what we both did as another possibility. The op is having the work done so a main panel upgrade will be more expensive but the job is 1 and done.

Comment: @EdBeal sorry if I came across as argumentative, just my clumsy attempt at recognizing your skill set. I think we agree that both options are a possibility. And I believe be both agree that a new main panel is the best route. I grew up in a house that started with one of those fuse boxes (yes FUSES) with the 2 pull out blocks and 4, count'em 4 circuits for the rest of the house.  Then a tiny sub-panel was added for something (dk what), then another, then another. Probably nothing up to code!  But when my parents went to electric heat, time for a new panel, unfortunately it was zinsco!

Comment: Awe come on Zinsco were good panels. My brother and I own our family home and guess what it has a Zinsco panel I installed. Yes they do have issues but there design was ahead of its time in some respects.

Comment: @EdBeal  I worked at a hard ware store when I was working my way thru college named "Pay 'n Pack".  ( A NW company, maybe you even had some in Bend).  Even though I was only about 19yo, I knew a lot about wiring.  I sold a ton of Zinsco panels. But long since then, after helping friends with Zinsco panels where the breakers wouldn't trip, or welded themselves to the bus bars, I realized they had issues.   Up here in Washington state, you can't even get insurance on a house if it has a Zinsco panel (or FP for that matter), not sure if that's justified, but it's the way it is.

Comment: The no trip comes from arcing of the aluminum buss if noalox was used they still work well, but any arcing and they are toast.

Answer (score 3):

### Rearranging this panel is *likely* possible, but not *guaranteed*

You have two free spaces in your panel, namely 7/9 and 8/10.  This is enough space that we can rearrange the bottom section to get another two-pole breaker in there; furthermore, since the top left of your panel accepts "double stuff" (half width) breakers, we can get 3 circuits in there, not just 2, and thus free up space 2 for a future subpanel, *provided* your panel can accept currently made GE breakers.

Your starting point is to move the single pole breaker in space 11/13 to space 8/10.  This frees up spaces 7/9 and 11/13 to have a 30A breaker popped in there for the EV charger, as even with a 7200VA (24A * 1.25 * 240V) charger atop the 4500VA of general lighting/receptacle and 4500VA of small appliance load there, you're still at a mere 51A@240VAC of Article 220 load on the bottom section thanks to the 35% demand factor for house (dwelling unit) lighting and receptacle loads upwards of 3kVA.

However, this is where things get a bit tricky, due to the age of your panel.  Normally, one'd just be able to pop a THQL2130 in and go, but your panel was built in a transitional era where GE was migrating from old style (TQL/TR, 5k AIC) breakers to a newer style of breaker (THQL/TQP/THQP, with half-width "skinny" breakers for double-stuffing instead of tandem breakers).  This wasn't a problem then, since both styles of breaker fit in your panel.  However, GE apparently (from the limited evidence I've seen) may have made a design change to their THQL breakers recently to make them not fit into panels older than yours that only are labeled for type TQL and TR breakers.  This means that I'd try the THQL2130 first, but if it doesn't fit quite right, *stop* and exchange the THQL2130 for an Eaton CL230 *UL classified* replacement breaker.  Also, if the THQL2130 doesn't fit, you'll want to schedule replacing the panel with a new one (or an Eaton retrofit kit) in the near future due to not being able to get enough room in the top section for a subpanel.

### If the shoe fits...

If the THQL2130 from above *does* fit, though, then we have more options.  While upgrading the split-bus feeder breaker is *possible* in this case, it's not technically *necessary* since you're under 60A in the bottom section even with the EV charger accounted for.  Instead, you're better off rearranging the *top* section to accommodate its full capacity of 4 240V circuits + the lighting main, as that gets you expansion room for a feeder to a future subpanel.  Note that while some split-bus panels can be fitted with a *backfed main breaker* using a *retainer kit* as per NEC 408.36(D), your GE panel most likely is not one of them, and furthermore, 200A GE plug-on breakers (TQDL21200) are not exactly stock items.

To rearrange the upper section, provided your panel can accept type THQP half-width "skinny" breakers, we'll need two THQP230s, a THQP250, and a THQL21125 for breakers, as well as a pair of TFP filler plates.  The TFP fillers, THQP230s, and THQP250 go into the upper left section of the panel, with the THQP230s in spaces 1 and 3 and the THQP250 in space 5.  The TFP fillers then fill in the unused "half spaces" at the top and bottom of this stack, while the THQL21125 goes into the top right in place of the existing 50A range breaker, and provides a 125A feeder for a future subpanel somewhere in the house.